# PhoneGap not loading local files

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build, phonegap-cli

So I was having this issue where no matter what I did, built PhoneGap apps wouldn't load JavaScript files. At first it seemed as if jQuery Mobile would not work or was broken, shortly after that it looked like this was because of an issue with the actual jQuery file. After a lot of trial and error I found that if I would refer the script to the jQuery CDNs and not the local files, it would work; both jQuery and jQuery mobile. Hours of headache go by but I have the answer for the people who were lucky enough to make the same mistake as me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue relates to the placement of the jQuery and jQuery Mobile files, or any js files for that matter. My mistake was placing the libraries in 'www/lib/jquery'. PhoneGap only compiles JavaScript files placed in the 'www/js' folder. Hopefully I helped someone out who was experiencing the same headache as me... If not, good luck on your further endeavors.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not wrong then you trying to place the "jquery.mobile.js" before the "jquery.js" in your HTML file.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="jquery.mobile.js"></script>
```

Further, don't forget to place the following in you "index.html"

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is not the case. I imported jQuery first, as Im meant to, and the cordova.js file is also imported.